# Error "Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.

```
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Process 'command '/Users/.../StudioProjects/../android/gradlew'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I was adding Firebase to my Flutter project. When I changed the *build.gradle* files in the app, as well as Application, this happened.

[image]

Comment: What is "phased action"? Is it "phased build action"? Or something else? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73401578/edit). Thanks in advance.